# Are scrolls and food worth it?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm currently new to Wow and have now the jobs herb gathering and glyph making, also the sub job cooking with which i cook the fishes a friend gets.

But by making the scrolls and the food i got buffs (i didnt knew this before...sorry xD)
and i wanted to ask if these "+3"-"+6" i'm currently making are worth it?

thank you for your answer i hope the question isn't to opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to boost your profession, but don't care about income, forget about leveling your main professions until Draenor and sell herbs you collect to finance your flying and other things. There you can craft all recipes starting with skill level 1.  However, it does take quite a while to get the resources needed, since you can only craft/order so many per day in your personal Fort.

*Opinion: Do try and keep them up to date, it will be less of a hassle later and to get the glyphs for your own class, but this profession is not very good for making money, except with the newest glyphs that everyone needs. The market is very tough, since they are permanent.*

More generally speaking, yes, entries that give you +2 skill points or more are worth it making. Why make an item that gives only +1 skill point if you can have up to +10 skill points for the same amount of material?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i didnt thought of "Item+2" -> "Scroll +10"

thank you^^

Comment: @KyoAkashi It is not +X Items, it means +X skill points. I clarified my answer.

Comment: The WoD crafted staves are very nice and I expect quite a few casters and the occasional druid to be picking them up as one of their three crafted items. But I expect this won't help the OP much if he doesn't make it to 90 before patch 6.1.